# Transform list data to summary table ( transpose and group ? )

Tags: python, transpose

I have data on speakers of many languages in different states/provinces,  for each state the number of speakers of a language are given by the government.

I want to summarize / transpose as shown in screenshot.  Where each language/state pair has no. speakers listed.

What is a good way to do in Python  or some other tool ?

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0z6F.png)

Data Sample CSV

```
State,Language,Speakers
ANDHRA PRADESH, Adi,37,
ARUNACHAL PRADESH, Adi,105158,
ASSAM, Adi,2992,
BIHAR, Adi,7,
CHHATTISGARH, Adi,6,
DADRA & NAGAR HAVELI, Adi,1,
GOA, Adi,1,
GUJARAT, Adi,3,
HARYANA, Adi,44,
HIMACHAL PRADESH, Adi,13,
JAMMU & KASHMIR, Adi,10,
JHARKHAND, Adi,9,
KARNATAKA, Adi,61,
KERALA, Adi,24,
MADHYA PRADESH, Adi,283,
MAHARASHTRA, Adi,9,
MANIPUR, Adi,20,
MEGHALAYA, Adi,207,
MIZORAM, Adi,17,
NAGALAND, Adi,60,
NCT OF DELHI, Adi,20,
ODISHA, Adi,1,
PUDUCHERRY, Adi,5,
PUNJAB, Adi,21,
RAJASTHAN, Adi,758,
SIKKIM, Adi,1,
TAMIL NADU, Adi,9,
TRIPURA, Adi,3,
UTTAR PRADESH, Adi,25,
UTTARAKHAND, Adi,6,
WEST BENGAL, Adi,496,
ARUNACHAL PRADESH, Henchul,27720,
ASSAM, Henchul,548,
BIHAR, Henchul,6,
CHANDIGARH, Henchul,2,
GOA, Henchul,4,
GUJARAT, Henchul,16,
HIMACHAL PRADESH, Henchul,69,
JAMMU & KASHMIR, Henchul,3,
JHARKHAND, Henchul,714,
KARNATAKA, Henchul,7,
KERALA, Henchul,4,
MAHARASHTRA, Henchul,3,
MANIPUR, Henchul,3,
MEGHALAYA, Henchul,77,
MIZORAM, Henchul,2,
NAGALAND, Henchul,6,
NCT OF DELHI, Henchul,1,
ODISHA, Henchul,1,
PUNJAB, Henchul,2,
RAJASTHAN, Henchul,9,
UTTAR PRADESH, Henchul,27,
UTTARAKHAND, Henchul,1,
WEST BENGAL, Henchul,21,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please try to not submit screen shots as part of your question.  You need to provide more information here.  Most critically, IMO, you need to tell us what the format of your data is, and where it's coming from.  If you can provide sample data in your question, that is best.  You also need to be clear about what you want to get out of your code.  Given your screenshot, I'm guessing that you want to produce a spreadsheet?  Is that true?  Finally, what have you already tried?  If you have some code written, show it to us. - Python will probably be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks Steve, sure will keep that in mind.  I have data in XLSX/CSV format.  I need the summary in either of the two formats. I am not too sure where to start but I guessed SQL or Python can do this.

Comment: How many columns in your data?  Can you post maybe the first 10-20 lines of the file in CSV format?

Comment: sure, just edited the post to include the 3 columns and the data sample

Comment: I don't understand how your sample data is different than what you say you want as a result.  How is what you want different than what you already have?  I'm probably just being stupid.

Comment: I have changed the sample for more clarity, there are multiple states where distribution of 2 languages Adi and Henchul is listed, but needs to be summarized without repeating the state names

Comment: I get it now.  I was being dumb.  I missed that you wanted the second form in the spreadsheet, on the right hand side.  So @gloxc88's answer might be a good starting point for you.  I don't know about Pandas, so I don't know how you get a CSV file into it.  I was working on a raw Python version.  Maybe I'll finish that and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming State, Language and Speakers are all columns in your dataframe you can simply use `pivot`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'State': ['State1', 'State2', 'State3', 'State1', 'State2', 'State3', 'State1', 'State2'],
        'Language': ['Lang1', 'Lang1', 'Lang1', 'Lang2', 'Lang2', 'Lang2', 'Lang3', 'Lang3'],
        'Speakers': [10, 100, 400, 1, 45, 100, 1000, 40]
    }
)

df.pivot(index='State', columns=['Language'], values='Speakers')


Language    Lang1   Lang2   Lang3
State           
State1      10.0    1.0     1000.0
State2      100.0   45.0    40.0
State3      400.0   100.0   NaN
```

Comment: Showing the result of that would be useful